# How to configure Puppeteer to write to a specific temp folder when using PM2 with a local windows service user?

Tags: node.js, windows-services, puppeteer, pm2, windows-server

We are running a Node.js backend on a Windows Server with `PM2`. For PDF generation we use `Puppeteer`.

**Chromium started with pm2 as Local Service user uses wrong temp folder**

Current installation:
PM2 is running as Service installed by using `pm2-installer` https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer) (using the offline installer, as the target is a windows server without internet). This PM2 starts a node application which starts a puppeteer-Chromium instance.
So this Chrome is running with the Local Service user.

Puppeteer is started using a specific userDataDir.

The Problem is now that Puppeteer tries to write to `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\...` where it does not have the permissions to write to as it is not running as Administrator.

Chrome debug log says: `Failed to create temporary file`

So the questions are:

- Why is Chrome writing to the Temp folder of the admin and not to a temp folder specific to the Local Service User or to the configured userDataDir (which is used by chrome for other files, so it's correctly configured)?
- How can I change Chromium to use a Temp folder it has permissions to?

Comment: Problem is still unsolved

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the temp directory by overriding the `PUPPETEER_TMP_DIR` environment variable. See their README for more information.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can change your puppeteer download path with `await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './mydownloadfolder'});`

Comment: `page._client.send is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

*Puppeteer looks for certain environment variables to aid its operations. If Puppeteer doesn't find them in the environment during the installation step, a lowercased variant of these variables will be used from the npm config.*

Set below environment variable

`PUPPETEER_TMP_DIR` - defines the directory to be used by Puppeteer for creating temporary files. Defaults to `os.tmpdir()`

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#environment-variables